# How to merge my branch to team master without ugly merge info

Tags: git, merge

I have my own `develop` branch copied from team's `master` branch and I have written some code to develop some features on the `develop` branch while the `master` branch is also developing by other team members.

Now I finished my module and would like to `merge` it to `master` branch but I set my git like this:

```
$ git config --global merge.ff only
```

Now when I try to `merge`, it gives

```
fatal: Not possible to fast-forward, aborting.
```

So what commands I should do in `Terminal` to `merge` it successfully and with no ugly merge info on the log.

Please be specific, many thanks.

Update: I don't know why people vote for closure since this is a very typical headache for git rookies.

If there are duplicates please lead them here since the answer is very good in my opinion and if this is not code/programming related please help or tell me where I should move it.

Comment: `with no ugly merge info on the log` ... unless the merge be a fast-forward (which isn't really a merge at all), then there will be a merge commit, and the potential conflicts which come with it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That is not completely true. You can also rebase the develop branch onto the master, or squash merge the develop branch into master. In both those cases, there will be no merge commits.

Comment: @Alderath The OP specifically mentioned _merging_ or else I would not have commented as I did above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will use an example to illustrate some alternatives.

Assume you have made the following two "Develop commit" commits on the `develop` branch, while there were two commits being made to the `master` branch:

```
* c302cd7 - (HEAD, develop) Develop commit 2
* 0a1fad1 - Develop commit 1
* fcf19a0 - Common commit
```

**Alternative 1: git merge**

Merge `develop` into `master`. Ie.:

```
git checkout master
git merge develop
```

This would result in a history looking like this:

```
*   e33bcaf - (HEAD, master) Merge branch 'develop'
|\  
| * c302cd7 - (develop) Develop commit 2
| * 0a1fad1 - Develop commit 1
* | 784442c - Master commit 2
* | 03c7803 - Master commit 1
|/  
* fcf19a0 - Common commit
```

As I understand, you do not want this. You want to avoid the merge commit (`e33bcaf` in the example above)

**Alternative 2: git merge --squash**

This approach will take all the changes from the `develop` branch and bundle them together into one squash commit.

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash develop
git commit
#enter apporpriate commit message describing the changes from develop branch
```

History will look like:

```
* 2fd2acc - (HEAD, master) Develop branch squash commit
* 784442c - Master commit 2
* 03c7803 - Master commit 1
* fcf19a0 - Common commit
```

**Alternative 3: git rebase**

You can let git try to reproduce the same changes that you made on the `develop` branch,
but starting from the latest version of the master branch instead. Note that this is not
a good idea if `develop` is a published branch which others are using. But if `develop`
is just your own local branch, this is okay.

```
git checkout develop
git rebase master
```

History will look like the following. If you want to, after this, you can merge `develop`
branch into `master` branch and that merge will be a fast forward.

```
* f1e329c - (HEAD, develop) Develop commit 2
* 066affd - Develop commit 1
* 784442c - (master) Master commit 2
* 03c7803 - Master commit 1
* fcf19a0 - Common commit
```

---

Note that for all the three alternatives, you may have to resolve merge conflicts if there are any.

Comment: It is very clear and specific, and I tried `git rebase` and it works fine to me, thanks.